# Golang jwt tokens don't properly save in redis

Tags: authentication, go, redis, jwt

When I save refresh and access token to redis they both save with a similar time, but I put different time for each one, they both setting to 30 days, but access token must be 15 minutes:

```
var(
    redisDb         = redis_jwt.RedisData{}
    redisController = rediscontroller.New(&redisDb)
    signKey         = os.Getenv("SigningKey")
    jwtRefreshExpiration = time.Now().Add(30 * (24 * time.Hour))
    jwtAccessExpiration  = time.Now().Add(1 * time.Hour)
)

// GenerateToken generates a jwt token with the specified claims and expiration time
func GenerateToken(claims jwt.MapClaims, expiration time.Time) (string, error) {
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    tokenStr, err := token.SignedString([]byte(signKey))
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Couldn't sign token: %v", err)
    }
    if id, ok := claims["RefreshToken"].(string); ok {
        err = redisController.SaveToken(redisDto.RedisDto{Token: tokenStr, Key: "RefreshToken", Id: id, Expiration: jwtRefreshExpiration})
        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Couldn't save refresh token to Redis: %v", err)
        }
    } else if id, ok := claims["AccesssToken"].(string); ok {
        err = redisController.SaveToken(redisDto.RedisDto{Token: tokenStr, Key: "AccessToken", Id: id, Expiration: jwtAccessExpiration})
        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Couldn't save access token to Redis: %v", err)
        }
    }
    return tokenStr, nil
}

// GenerateRefreshToken generates a refresh token for the specified user ID
func GenerateRefreshToken(userId string) (string, error) {
    claims := jwt.MapClaims{
        "RefreshToken": userId,
        "exp":          jwtRefreshExpiration,
    }
    return GenerateToken(claims, jwtRefreshExpiration)
}

// GenerateAccessToken generates an access token for the specified user ID
func GenerateAccessToken(userId string) (string, error) {
    claims := jwt.MapClaims{
        "AccesssToken": userId,
        "exp":          jwtAccessExpiration,
    }

    return GenerateToken(claims, jwtAccessExpiration)
}
```

---

Here is a controller func:

```
func (c *RdbController) SaveToken(data dto.RedisDto) error {
    var dbData redis_jwt.RedisData
    err := parseToDb(data, &dbData)
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }
    err = c.redis.SaveToken(dbData)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

And db function:

```
func (u *RedisData) SaveToken(userData RedisData) error {
    pipeline := RedisDb.Pipeline()
    pipeline.HSet(ctx, userData.Id, userData.Key, userData.Token)
    pipeline.Expire(ctx, userData.Id, userData.Expiration.Sub(time.Now()))
    result, err := pipeline.Exec(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, command := range result {
        if err = command.Err(); err != nil {
            pipeline.Discard()
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

.....................................................................................

Comment: what is RedisDb?  looks like it might be the commonly used go-redis?

Comment: @erik258
Yep:
var (
 RedisDb = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
  Addr:     os.Getenv("RedisAddr"),
  Username: os.Getenv("RedisUsername"),
  Password: os.Getenv("RedisPassword"),
 })
 ctx = context.Background()
)